# How to make images line up in a row regardless of browser zoom level?

Tags: html, css, image, position, alignment

It seems that no matter what I do, I can't get a row of images to line up horizontally when I zoom into the browser. When I zoom in, the images furthest to the right will drop down to the next row instead of going off screen. I've tried `float:left;`, creating a border, and `position:relative;` but no luck.

If I use `position:absolute;` it seems like I have to manually position each image.

My goal is make a sliding image gallery using jquery like the one here: http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/elegant-sliding-image-gallery-with-jquery/

I don't want to copy the code in the link above, because I want to create everything from scratch by understanding the fundamental building blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try wrapping the images in a container div width 100%, with `overflow: hidden;` this will stop a scroll bar appearing -  Then set the `white-space` property of the container div to `nowrap` this should force the images to stay on one line but the overflow outside your container area will be hidden allowing you to script the change to the left/right offset or margin - you can make the images display inline, or inline-block

Nate that if there is also caption text along with these images the white-space property will also affect the text in the captions so you may need to reset any captions to `white-space: normal`

**sample CSS:**

```
#container {
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 3px double #000;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#container img {display: inline-block; margin: 0 100px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating a container div around the images with fixed width, i.e.: in px

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    #container { width:1100px; }
    img { width:200px; height:100px; margin: 0 10px; float:left; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```